# How to generate the "vectors" in input layer for text classification?

Tags: vector, keras, lstm

I was thinking of using Keras to implement a document classification task, but the input of the LSTM layer is confusing me.

I know I have to generate the vectors for training, I have a corpus and one document per line in this corpus, if I would like to feed the corpus into the LSTM layer, do I need to first generate the document vectors from the corpus for training? Or instead of using word-level vectors, or character-level vectors?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. Can you show us how your data looks like? What you want to model? This question is a bit vague.

Comment: @nemo, my data looks like: literature title, literature abstract. My purpose is to training the title and corresponding abstract together. I was thinking of use the siamese network for training.

Answer (score 0):

In a document classification task, if you use LSTM the outputs are typically  word-level vectors, which can be either pre-trained or randomly initialized. You can combine word-level vectors with character-level vectors, e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.03475

Comment: Thanks Franck, but I am a little confused about the output, why it would be a word-level vectors?These vectors mean the probability of the "class"? Or just generate the word vectors?